# Laurent series about which point?

Tags: laurent-series, singularity-theory

I have been given the question: "Find the laurent series of $1/(1-z^3)$". No other information.

The question was posed in the process of finding the series' residual and in the answer I can see that there's a simple pole at $z=1$. However, just from the question itself there is no information on which point I should be expanding it. In that case, I expanded about $z = 0$ which results in a series without any poles. Of course, I notice the singularity at $z=1$ and could have made the substitution $u=z-1$ and expanded from there. Is this the general method for a Laurent series? I would have thought the expansion would be about $z=0$ if there is no other information?

In addition, I have tried to find the Laurent series about $z=1$ but am not getting the right answer.

My method: let $u = z-1$:

$f(u) = 1/(1-(u+1)^3) = 1 + (u+1)^3 + (u+1)^6 + ...$

Does the binomial expansion not work for this?

Comment: You are correct that the statement, with no point specified, can't be interpreted. Similarly for "Taylor series of $f$" with no point specified. Whereas "Maclaurin series of $f$" is well-defined.

Comment: Well, if you need to find residuals at some point $z_0$, then you should take the Laurent expansion at $z_0$...

Comment: What about the Laurent expansion on $\{z: |z|>1\}$?